# iOS 8 - iAds live crash in prod but working on simulator

Tags: ios, ios8, iad

I've got unexpected crashes with the iAds banner in iOS8.
I've implemented the delegate "`bannerViewDidFailToReceiveAdWithError:`", the code enters it when it failed to receive the ad.
But event with this, the application crashes.

**Here's the log :**

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   Security                        0x2abb40b6 SecKeyGetBlockSize + 2
1   MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x001b92d8 0x70000 + 1348312
2   MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x001b9070 0x70000 + 1347696
3   MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x001b8c0c 0x70000 + 1346572
4   MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x001ba2de 0x70000 + 1352414
5   MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x00162262 0x70000 + 991842
6   MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x0015c7ba 0x70000 + 968634
7   MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x0015c8c8 0x70000 + 968904
8   MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x0015c9fa 0x70000 + 969210
9   MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x0014c516 0x70000 + 902422
10  MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x001433d0 0x70000 + 865232
11  MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x00142d98 0x70000 + 863640
12  MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x000d4a6a 0x70000 + 412266
13  MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x0026cc8c 0x70000 + 2083980
14  MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x0025ed1c 0x70000 + 2026780
15  MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x00260788 0x70000 + 2033544
16  MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x00281b84 0x70000 + 2169732
17  MogoHoroscopeNewLite            0x001414a8 0x70000 + 857256
18  iAd                             0x2b8c23ba -[ADBannerView _forwardErrorToDelegate:] + 250
19  iAd                             0x2b8c1c8e -[ADBannerView serverBannerViewDidFailToReceiveAdWithError:] + 174
```

Comment: Can you track it with the debugger in Xcode? Is it crashing within your error handler?

Comment: I can't. Those crashes occures on the client's devices. So I only have access to the stacktrace on iTunesConnect. The errorHandler not raising too.

Comment: Do you native display iAds or do you do with another service ?

Comment: AdMob mediation service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated to the last iAd adapter for Google Ad Mob Mediation.

Here's the link : https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/mediation-networks?hl=fr

Google forgot to notify that an update was available since 22th september 2014.